# How to deploy a WAR file into Apache 2.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache2

My server is an apache 2.2 who serves php applications, now I would like to configure it to serve J2EE applications as well.

I think there is an Apache module to deploy WAR files into it, Could anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Apache is a web server.  It doesn't have a servlet/JSP engine built into it.

You can install Tomcat, which is a servlet/JSP engine, and configure Apache to forward requests for servlets and JSPs to it.

You should also know that Tomcat is not a full Java EE app server.  It's a servlet/JSP engine, just a subset of Java EE.  It doesn't have capabilities for EJBs or JMS.  You'll have to add OpenEJB and ActiveMQ to Tomcat to get those.

Answer (score 3):

Apache + mod_proxy + Java EE application server (tomcat + openejb, glassfish, jboss...)