# Spring MVC project in apache web server (httpd)

Tags: java, apache, spring-mvc, vps

I know deploying Spring MVC outcome to Apache Tomcat is obvious. Is it possible to deploy to Apache Web Server (HTTPD).
I need to deploy my project without VPS in web.

Comment: If you have a `war` archive, you need a *Servlet Container* in order to run your application.  But still you can put the Apache Web Server in front of a Servlet Container like Tomcat and route requests to Tomcat. If you don't want to use a Standalone Servlet Container, using an embedded one is also an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a WAR file into Apache 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646821/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-into-apache-2-2)

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the comments you will need a servlet container to run your spring application. Usually you will then put a webserver (apache, nginx) in front of that. For Apache there are actually 3 ways to achieve this.

**1. Use mod_proxy**

Install and enable mod_proxy on your apache webserver. Then in a VirtualHost directive you can enable forwarding requests adding the following to your configuration:

```
ProxyPass /path-to-your-application "http://host:port/context"
```

Further options can be found here: [Apache mod_proxy documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html)

**2. Use mod_ajp**

Another way is to use mod_ajp. AJP is a binary protocol that has some performance advantages over using mod_proxy. 
To use mod_ajp you will need a workers file. The location of the workers file is usually configured in the configuration file of mod_ajp. On Ubuntu/Debian you will find this in:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.conf
```

The workers file is a properties file containing the configuration of a servlet container that will be used for communication. A basic example could look like this:

```
worker.foobar.port=8009
worker.foobar.type=ajp13
worker.foobar.host=localhost
```

Note that the word 'foobar' here is the name for the worker. You will need this later on. Having this configured and mod_ajp enabled you need to add a JkMount directive to your host configuration. This could look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ...
    JkMount /*     foobar
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This would send all incoming requests on that virtual host to the worker named 'foobar' which is pointed to the servlet container configured in your workers file.

**3. Use mod_proxy_ajp**

Writing this anwer I've seen that there is another way to configure ajp using mod_proxy. For this to work you will need mod_proxy and mod_proxy_ajp

Within you VirtualHost you can define a proxy with:

```
ProxyPass / "ajp://host:port/context"
```

Haven't used this myself I guess this is a very convenient way to use both modules with an easy way of configuration. See [mod_proxy_ajp documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) for further reading.